# How to use create nested object and use f.select for all objects of an associated class? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a Candy Shop simulation.

**Problem #1:**

How can I create a candy object with the form?  I have changed the association and now it no longer creates a candy object (even though I tried to make "shelf" an optional attribute for a "candy" object). How can I create a "candy" without an existing "shelf" but allow "shelf" to have many candies? This is the previous working code:

```
<table>
<h3>Create Candy</h3>
<%= form_for([@shop, @shop.candies.build]) do |f| %>
<p>
   <tr>
    <td>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.submit %>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </p>
<% end %>
</table>
```

**Problem #2**

I would like to use a form to select objects of a class called "Shelf" when creating a object called "Candy". I would like the user to have the option to choose from "NA" (a nil value shelf) or an existing shelf(shown by its name like shelf.name). A candy does not have to have a shelf attribute, it is optional (ie. a shelf can be empty). I am new to ROR and very unsure on how to go about this.

Note: I placed "candies" in routes twice in an attempt to have the "shelf" attribute be optional for candy.

Models:

shop.rb

```
Shop has_many :candies 
Shop has_many :shelves
```

shelf.rb

```
Shelf has_many :candies 
belongs_to :shop
```

candy.rb

```
belongs_to :shop 
belongs_to :shelf, optional: true
```

In routes: 
routes.rb

```
resources :shops do 
    resources :candies 
    resources :shelves do 
        resources :candies 
    end 
end
```

I have been trying different variations of this code below:

```
<table>
    <h3>Create Candy</h3>
    <%= form_for([@shop, @shop.candies.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
       <tr>
        <td>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :shop_id %>
        <%= f.select :shop_id, options_for_select(shop.all.map{shops_name}, {'NA'}, {class: 
        "form-control selectpicker", data: {"live-search": true}
        <%= f.submit %>
        </td>
       </tr>
     </p>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

Comment: _"How can I create a candy object with the form?"_ - What is the issue?

Comment: _"I would like the user to have the option to choose from "NA" (a nil value shelf) or an existing shelf"_ - So, what's the problem?

Comment: The code I have will not allow me to create a candy object, it no longer works after I changed the way I nested my resources.  I do not know how I would code the part to select it. The code I have does not work.  I have tried different variations but I am not understanding what I did wrong.  Thank you.

Comment: You will need to explain "does not work" part a bit more. What do you see?